# How do i assign a lazyloaded component to Routes.js in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, server-side-rendering

I've inherited a SSR app from someone and i'm having trouble code-splitting.

Basically i hand a React Loadable version of MyPage and i get issues.

[Not sure i'm understanding the architecture of SSR correctly]

If i use React-Loadable or Loadable Components. or even just write my own... the routes.js file will fail with `this usually happens when you forgot to export...`. Though obviously i haven't done that.

```
routes.js

const routes = [
//  lots of routes
  {
    ...MyPage,
    path: '/test-ssr'
  },
//  lots of routes
```

```
server/react/index.js

const renderReactRoute = async (res, url) => {

  const store = configureStore({
    api: {}
  });

  const activeRoute = fetchComponentData(url, store, routes);
  if (activeRoute.requests.length) await Promise.all(activeRoute.requests);
  // ^^ awaiting for the fetchData() reqs to resolve

  // react-router Context
  const context = {};

  const htmlString = template(store.getState(), config, renderToString(
    <Provider store={ store }>
      <StaticRouter location={ url } context={ context }>
        { renderRoutes(routes) }
      </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
  ), Helmet.renderStatic(), res);

  ...

  ...
  return htmlString;
}

router.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  renderReactRoute(res, req.url)
   .then(htmlString => {
    if (!res.headersSent) {
      res.send(htmlString);
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    return next(err);
  });
});
```

So it matches the route, waits for everything to resolve.

For clarity, `<MyPage />` is a functional component, which has a `.fetchData()` bolted on, similar to getInitialProps on nextJS. But this is NOT nextJS. It's just React, Redux and React Router.

```
client/pages/MyPage/MyPage.js

import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getPageByPath } from '../../routes';

function MyPage({ match, content, fetchPage }) {

  const checkPrismicData = async () => {
    if (!content) {
      await fetchPage(match.params.uid);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkPrismicData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>i am a page</h1>
    </div>
  );
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  content: state.some.content
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchPage: () => dispatch(fetchPageAction())
});

MyPage.fetchData = async (store, props) => {
  const currentPage = getPageByPath(props.path);
  return Promise.all([
    store.dispatch(fetchPageAction(currentPage.uid)),
  ]);
};

export default {
  component: connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyPage)
};
// NOTE ^^ exported as an object so every page in SSR code it can fire off `WrappedComponent.fetchData && WrappedComponent.fetchData(store, props)`
```

- ALL of the prismic data returns fine.
- but inside routes:

```
  {
    ...MyPage,
    path: '/test-ssr'
  },
```

This is basically saying:

```
{
  component: MyPage, (including the fetchData() func)
  path: '/test-ssr',
}
```

And then that fetchData is called, as above^^.

But here's the problem: *How* do you handle that if the MyPage you're handing to the route is *actually* `LazyMyPage` like:

```
const LazyMyPage = Loadable({
 loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "MyPage" */'./pages/MyPage/MyPage'),
 loading: Loading
});

{
  component: LazyMyPage ????
  path: '/test-ssr',
}
```